# Laravel 4 passwords and python

Tags: php, python, hash, laravel, laravel-4

I have a hashed password using the Hash::make() function of laravel when a user is created.  I eventually need to take that hashed password, and pass it to a python script to perform a login and download of site resources.  I know the hash is a one-way action, but I'd like to keep the password hashed to be security conscious if at all possible.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this task while keeping security intact would be helpful!

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: What actors do you control? Can you modify the site you are downloading from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant the best you can do is encrypt it with a reversible encryption ... but then you need to store the key somewhere ... eventually you will have some plain text somewhere (or encoded at best) that will allow decryption ... you could store the hash and do a query against a db that maps hashes to pw's but you still have the password in plaintext somewhere ... you cannot login with just a hash anywhere ... (because the hash ends up getting hashed and then no longer matches the expected hash)

an option may be to use rainbow tables to find something that results in an identical hash and use that instead ... but if they are adding salts or anything you are once again out of luck

Comment: Thanks Joran, you confirmed what I suspected... just good to get a second opinion.